# Why is this Python function not passed by reference?

Tags: python, function, class, reference, pass-by-reference

```
def funcA():
    print("No")

def funcB():
    print("Yes")

class A:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    
    def getB(self):
        b = B(self.func)
        return b

    def setfunc(self, func):
        self.func = func


class B:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    
    def execfunc(self):
        self.func()


a = A(funcA)
b = a.getB()
a.setfunc(funcB)
b.execfunc()
```

1. I create A and set A.func to be funcA (print "No")
2. I create B and set B.func = A.func = funcA (print "No")
3. I change A.func to be funcB (print "Yes")
4. I execute B.func and it executes funcA (print "No")

If in step 2 the function was passed by reference, and the function target was changed in step 3, why does B.func not change to the new target?

Comment: Python does not use 'pass by reference'.

Comment: @Wombatz Python does though, see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pass-by-reference-vs-value-in-python#:~:text=All%20parameters%20(arguments)%20in%20the,back%20in%20the%20calling%20function.

Comment: maybe it even `pass by reference` to function but assignment `=`  doesn't have to do the same - and finally you have something different then you expect.

Comment: Python is pass by value, but the value of every variable (indeed, every expression) **is** a reference.  This seemingly pedantic distinction is the key to enlightenment.

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @Tjeerd the first paragraph in the linked tutorialspoint page is utterly wrong. It would be true for a C++ reference, but not for python. If their claim was right then their second example would produce a different output.